# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: _BN_new

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I'm trying to compile this super simple code:

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main(void)
{
    BIGNUM *k = BN_new();
}
```

I use the following command:

```
gcc-11 test.c -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
```

I get

```
gcc-11 test.c -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_BN_new", referenced from:
      _main in ccRnO859.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is more information:

```
% file $(which gcc-11)
/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
% gcc-11 --version                                                       
gcc-11 (Homebrew GCC 11.1.0) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
% file /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib           
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
% nm -gU /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib|grep _BN_new  
00000000000311bc T _BN_new
```

EDIT: I tried exactly the same with a x86_64 version of GCC and OpenSSL, it gives the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, this function is defined in the `libcrypto` library, but you did not actually link with that library.    You need to add `-lcrypto` to the end of your linker command line.

The `-L` option specifies a directory to be searched for libraries requested with `-l` options, but does not itself add any libraries to the link.